# My cat's rear end smells like acid

Tags: cats, health

One of my cats just jumped in my lap and I started petting her like usual. She turned and faced away as she was getting comfortable, and I had a strong whiff of what I can only describe as acid. There's no poop smell or typical cat urine smell, and their litter box is normal. She looks like she might be a little wet in that area, but she's not dripping or anything like that. The other cat is fine, only one has this issue, and the other cat is treating her normally as though nothing is wrong.

I've looked around my apartment and there's nothing abnormal around, she didn't sit in anything. My apartment isn't very large, so I'm confident that I didn't miss anything.

What could this be? My nostrils feel like they're actually burning from the acid-like smell, it was *incredibly* strong.

Comment: is your cat spayed and is this cat indoor only,what is the age of your cat.i think you shuld take your cat to the vet for this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the scent of anal glands? That's my first guess. It's pretty awful but not a health concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw the vet today (they had an opening, it wasn't an emergency appointment). Hew said it's just the anal glands and nothing is wrong, they're not impacted or infected. He expressed them (squeezed them, I guess) and sent me on my way with info about some pet sprays that I can just spray directly on the cat if I smell it.